# How to calculate time difference in sql

Tags: oracle

I have one table named  `test`.
In that table I have a column named  `test_time` of type `DATE`. I want to calculate the time difference between test_time and sysdate in minutes.

```
select 1440 * (to_date('2009-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')
- to_date('2009-07-07   19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_hours 
from dual;
```

this one giving time difference in minutes. But I tried this one to my table like

```
select 1440 * (to_date(test_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')
- to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_hours 
from test;
```

but I'm not able to calculate the time difference in minutes. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the data type of the column `test_time`

Comment: Data type is Date only

Answer (score 4):

`DATE`is the Oracle datetime data type for storing a datetime value with a precision of one second.  The function `TO_DATE` converts a character type (`VARCHAR2`,`CHAR`,...)  to the `DATE` type. The first string is the string to convert, the secons string tell the convert function which format is used to code the date in the first string. So the result of  `TO_DATE('2014-04-18 10:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')` is the DATE  equivalent to '2014-04-18 10:33:00'. The seconds are set to 0.

The function `SYSDATE` returns a `DATE` value  so it must not be converted further. The column  `test_time` is of data type `DATE`, too, it also must not be converted further. To get the `DATE`difference you have only to calculate `test_time-SYSDATE` This difference of two DATE values gives the number of days. Therefore you have to multiply the above value by 1440 (=24*60, the number of minutes per day). You end up with

```
select (test_time - sysdate)*24*60
  from test;
```

This value is negative if test_time is lies in the past. If you want an integer value then round the  result

```
select round((test_time - sysdate)*24*60,0)
  from test;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Now am clear with this to_date function.we need to multiply that 24*60 instead of dividing for getting minutes or not.